# How to increment date by month in pandas dataframe within a date column then update the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a pandas dataframe with a date column. I need to be able to increment the date inside `date column` by number of months that i define custom, hence update the dataframe to reflect the new incremented date.

Have researched and tried to fix my code however its failing with the error below.
`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "DateOffset") to str`

My dataframe code

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_posts': [4, 6, 3, 9, 1, 14, 2, 5, 7, 2],
                   'date': ['2020-08-09', '2020-08-25', 
                            '2020-09-05', '2020-09-12', 
                            '2020-09-29', '2020-10-15',
                            '2020-11-21', '2020-12-02', 
                            '2020-12-10', '2020-12-18']})
```

My code for incrementing the date column by number of months i define.

```
# increment date by one month
plus_month_period = 1
df['date'] + pd.DateOffset(months=plus_month_period)
df
```

What can i do to resolve the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting your object to a datetime object first

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_posts': [4, 6, 3, 9, 1, 14, 2, 5, 7, 2],
                   'date': ['2020-08-09', '2020-08-25', 
                            '2020-09-05', '2020-09-12', 
                            '2020-09-29', '2020-10-15',
                            '2020-11-21', '2020-12-02', 
                            '2020-12-10', '2020-12-18']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
plus_month_period = 1
df = df['date'] + pd.DateOffset(months=plus_month_period)
```

Comment: I'm getting this from dataframe `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_16128\1282108890.py:111: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy` The dataframe date column is already in `dtype of datetime64`